# Using a PHP Counter and want to use multiples of 3

Tags: php

I've got this code here

```
<?php
$COUNT = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." & $count % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<td><a href='$entry'>$entry</a></td>";
        echo $Count;
        $Count++;

    }
    else {echo "<tr><td><a href='$entry'>$entry</a></td><tr>";
    echo $Count;
    $Count++;
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

and I just can't seem to get it to work. I want a new table row every time the counter is a mutiple of 3.

Comment: "and I just can't seem to get it to work" --- Have you looked at the generated html? As a first step - write **manually** what you want to achieve and **only after** that program it

Comment: @zerkms I get: http://pastebin.com/L7w0q6pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `$COUNT`, `$Count`, and `$count` in your script like they are the same variable. They are not. PHP variables are case sensitive. Change them all to `$count` and it *should* work.

If you turn error_reporting on so it reports notices, as you should always do in development, you would have caught this quickly.

Comment: It won't - just look how he generates rows

Comment: Wow. I didn't see past the obvious mistake to see how bad that was.

Comment: Oopsie. Major oversight. I've fixed

Comment: Still having problems. If you go here you will see it... http://jamiehankins.co.uk/pics/

Comment: I echoed at each step and I got: table row row table row row table row row table row row table row row table row row table row row table row row table row row table row

Answer (score 0):

In additional to @John Conde : use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: Done. Still not how I'd like it to look

Comment: Your code will generate something like `...<td>...</td><tr><td>...</td></tr><td>...</td>...`. You need something like `<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>`

Comment: I've fixed it now. I noticed the table row row and swapped table and row about. Thanks :)